# For an Android soft keyboard, what are the Latin 1 keycodes? And all the UTF-8 ones, too?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I looked through a lot of Android documentation and could not find a simple list of keycodes. The list on the developer site (a header file) does not match the codes in the Android Sample Softkeyboard.

I was able to find that the easy way to upper-case a letter was:

```
primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
```

Below is the link I found for Latin 1.  If anyone finds a big list for all of UTF-8, please post it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link I found for the 256 codes of Latin 1:

http://oreilly.com/actionscript/excerpts/actionscript-for-flash/appendix-b.html

Answer (score 0):

**And here is the utf-8 list**, in more different ways than any one person could use. A very thorough site.

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/